# The meaning of 'Let her out' when driving a car

Tags: meaning

When you say to a driver "Let her out" referring to a car, do you mean "let's drive fast"? 
Can you say like that?
I am reading a story and there is such a phrase:

> "Let her out, Frank," called he to his chauffeur, as we rounded into a
>   broad and now almost deserted thoroughfare.

In which situations can one say this?

Comment: Though cars are certainly personified, 'Let somebody out' as a title here just does not work.

Comment: I've re-edited. 'Let her out' certainly means 'Open her up', ie 'Speed up' (with a hint of _rapid_ acceleration). I'm not sure that it's not a reference to what happens to the accelerator cable when the pedal is depressed (or an equivalent in older cars), but with transferred usage to the car herself.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! As i understood the person saying it using kind of humour, meaning to speed up

Comment: It's more of a male appetite for speed and the open road (I don't think many ladies refer to cars as '_she_'s). 'Let her rip!' (Don't 'accept' an answer, especially one without references, for a day or so; someone may hopefully find a validated etymology of the phrase).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok, thank you for your advice. In my language a word car has a female gender. We call it she, that's why i thought that the narrator meant his car calling it "she".

Comment: What's your native language? In French, a car is either un automobile or une voiture; the words themselves are marked as 'masculine' or 'feminine'. But in English, words do not have inherent gender (though there are words signifying male and female sentient beings, like man/woman; bull/cow; tomcat/she-cat ...). But inanimate objects (and emotions, ideas, concepts, states ...) are seen as neuter and use the pronoun 'it' rather than 'he' or 'she'. **Except that** men's pet possessions etc like boats, cars, locomotives ... are often personified, then always using 'she' / 'her' in place of 'it'.

Comment: My language is russian, but in many languages,  they have genders. Thanks for information about the personification of possessions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth fwiw in French the car might well be *“la bagnole”*, *“elle”* or (as I discovered on another SE site) ***“[ma titine](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/meaning-of-a-phrase-with-focus-on-the-word-titine)”***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is speculation! If someone has anything definitive, I'd be happy to hear it!

This is an older usage (mid-1950s is the latest I can think of). It references horses or other animals and "letting them out" to stretch their legs - to trot, gallop, run, or otherwise go fast.

Comment: Yep, I'm reasonably certain that "Let her out", for automobiles, originated as a sort of metaphorical reference to letting loose on the reins of a team of horses pulling a wagon, so that the horses would run faster.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/do-you-rein-in-or-reign-in-something

Answer (score 0):

@farfromunique's answer is already quite correct, but for future visitors, there are *three* situations in which one can say [while sitting in a car and speaking to the driver], *“let her out”*, *viz*:

- you want them to put on a burst of speed, as in the OPs example
- to mean “Stop here and open the door to allow our passenger to get out of the car”
- to mean “Pause for a moment so that that car over there can pull out of the turning first, we’re not in any hurry, and they seem to have been waiting a while”

Comment: That's a great explanation, thank you!